# Load Picker View options from online JSON file

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to grab a JSON file from the internet that would basically look like this but may have more or less values in the future:

```
["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]
```

My question is, rather than specifying an array of what to use in the UIPicker, how can I have the options from the JSON file loaded in?

Comment: IMO not possible. You have to make an Array or Dictionary of the JSON data for it to be shown in the Picker View, Collection View or Table View.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all the elements to form an array and use that array to fill the picker view and reload it as

```
    [contentPickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [contentPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where exactly does this code go because it is throwing errors?

Comment: The time when you have gathered all JSON elements in an array then reload the pickerview